Issue with Accessing FastAPI Microservice via Nginx in Docker Setup
I'm working on a Dockerized application that consists of a FastAPI backend (Microservice 1) and an Nginx server (Microservice 2) which serves as a reverse proxy and also serves static files. Everything seems to be running without errors, but I'm facing two significant issues:
Project structure:
- microservice-1/
  - Dockerfile
  - main.py
  - requirements.txt
- microservice-2/
  - Dockerfile
  - static/
    - index.html
    - styles.css
- nginx/
  - nginx.conf
- docker-compose.yml

Docker Compose File:
version: '3.8'

services:
  postgres-db:
    image: postgres:latest
    restart: always
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: mysecretpassword
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    networks:
      - webapp-network

  microservice-1:
    build:
      context: ./microservice-1
    container_name: microservice-1
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    environment:
      DATABASE_URL: postgresql://postgres:mysecretpassword@postgres-db/postgres
    depends_on:
      - postgres-db
    networks:
      - webapp-network

  microservice-2:
    build:
      context: ./microservice-2
    container_name: microservice-2
    ports:
      - "8081:80"
    networks:
      - webapp-network

  nginx:
    image: nginx:alpine
    ports:
      - "8082:80"
    volumes:
      - ./nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:ro
    depends_on:
      - microservice-1
      - microservice-2
    networks:
      - webapp-network

networks:
  webapp-network:
    driver: bridge

Nginx Configuration (nginx/nginx.conf):
server {
    listen 80;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://microservice-1:8080;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
}

FastAPI Code (microservice-1/main.py):
from fastapi import FastAPI, HTTPException, Depends
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, Column, Integer, String, Float
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker, Session
from pydantic import BaseModel

app = FastAPI()

DATABASE_URL = "postgresql://postgres:mysecretpassword@postgres-db/postgres"
engine = create_engine(DATABASE_URL)
Base = declarative_base()
SessionLocal = sessionmaker(autocommit=False, autoflush=False, bind=engine)

class Movie(Base):
    __tablename__ = "movies"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    name = Column(String, index=True, unique=True)
    rating = Column(Float)

Base.metadata.create_all(bind=engine)

class MovieCreate(BaseModel):
    name: str
    rating: float

def get_db():
    db = SessionLocal()
    try:
        yield db
    finally:
        db.close()

@app.post("/movies/")
def add_movie(movie: MovieCreate, db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
    db_movie = db.query(Movie).filter(Movie.name == movie.name).first()
    if db_movie:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=400, detail="Movie already exists")
    new_movie = Movie(name=movie.name, rating=movie.rating)
    db.add(new_movie)
    db.commit()
    return {"message": "Movie added successfully"}

@app.get("/movies/{movie_name}")
def get_movie(movie_name: str, db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
    movie = db.query(Movie).filter(Movie.name == movie_name).first()
    if not movie:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=404, detail="Movie not found")
    return {"movie_name": movie.name, "average_rating": movie.rating}

Issues:
1. Accessing the FastAPI service via Nginx: When I try to access the FastAPI endpoints through Nginx using http://localhost:8082, I get a "Connection Refused" error.
Curl directly to FastAPI (works):
curl -X POST "http://localhost:8080/movies/" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"name": "Scream", "rating": 8.5}'
{"message":"Movie added successfully"}

Curl via Nginx (fails):
curl -X POST "http://localhost:8082/movies/" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"name": "Scream", "rating": 8.5}'
curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 8082: Connection refused

2. Frontend Static Files Not Served Correctly:
The frontend at localhost:8081 loads, but the static files (e.g., styles.css) either aren't properly served or are generating errors.
microservice-2  | 172.20.0.1 - - [30/Aug/2024:19:56:08 +0000] "GET /styles.css HTTP/1.1" 304 0 "http://localhost:8081/?" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/128.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" "-"

Here's my index.html:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Movie Ratings</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Movie Ratings</h1>

    <div id="tab1">
        <h2>Get Average Rating</h2>
        <form id="getRatingForm">
            <label for="movieName">Movie Name:</label>
            <select id="movieName" name="movieName">
                <!-- Options populated dynamically via JS -->
            </select>
            <button type="button" onclick="getRating()">Get Rating</button>
        </form>
        <div id="ratingResult"></div>
    </div>

    <div id="tab2">
        <h2>Add a Rating</h2>
        <form id="addRatingForm">
            <label for="movieNameInput">Movie Name:</label>
            <input type="text" id="movieNameInput" name="movieName">
            <label for="rating">Rating:</label>
            <input type="number" id="rating" name="rating" min="0" max="10" step="0.1">
            <button type="button" onclick="addRating()">Add Rating</button>
        </form>
        <div id="addResult"></div>
    </div>

    <script>
        function getRating() {
            const movieName = document.getElementById("movieName").value;
            fetch(`/movies/${movieName}`)
                .then(response => response.json())
                .then(data => document.getElementById("ratingResult").innerText = `Average Rating: ${data.average_rating}`);
        }

        function addRating() {
            const movieName = document.getElementById("movieNameInput").value;
            const rating = document.getElementById("rating").value;
            fetch("/movies/", {
                method: "POST",
                headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
                body: JSON.stringify({ name: movieName, rating: parseFloat(rating) })
            })
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => document.getElementById("addResult").innerText = data.message);
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>

Here is styles.css:
body {
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    background-color: #f4f4f4;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    height: 100vh;
    color: #333;
}

h1 {
    color: #4CAF50;
}

#tab1, #tab2 {
    background-color: #fff;
    padding: 20px;
    margin: 20px;
    border-radius: 8px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    width: 300px;
}

h2 {
    color: #555;
}

form {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

label {
    margin-bottom: 8px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

input, select, button {
    padding: 8px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 4px;
    font-size: 14px;
}

button {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: #fff;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: background-color 0.3s ease;
}

button:hover {
    background-color: #45a049;
}

#ratingResult, #addResult {
    margin-top: 10px;
    font-style: italic;
    color: #333;
}

I’m unsure if the problem lies with how the containers are set up, the Nginx configuration, or something else. Any advice or insights would be greatly appreciated!
